# What functors preserve subobject classifiers?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

My question is exactly that of the title. Given a topos $T$, is there a natural sufficient condition for a functor $f$ from $T$ to another topos, $S$, to the subobject classifier? (By this I mean of course that not only that $f$ sends $\Omega_T$ to $\Omega_S$, but also that $f$ acts on morphisms in the appropriate way with respect to the subobject classifier's defining diagram.)

Comment: Yes, it looks like I am - I definitely should have looked at nLab first. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [logical functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logical+functor) preserves the topos structure; in particular, preserves power objects, and so maps $\Omega_T = \mathcal{P} 1_T$ to $\Omega_S = \mathcal{P} 1_S$.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it is somehow tautological. But of course this is because of the rather empty question ...